# Gaussian Elimination - Is this fellow student correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an student who is telling me that if I have a matrix $A$, and a final matrix $b$, that multiplying $A*b$ will give me the solution of systems matrix $x$. I know that a system of linear equations can be represented as:

$$Ax = b$$

What this fellow student is telling me is that if we generate a random $A$ and a random $b$, that if we do the following, we can get $x$:

$$Ab = x$$

Algebraically, this just seems blatantly wrong; not to mention logically as well, otherwise what would be the point of Gaussian Elimination??

Now the problem set:

- Take user input as $N$
- Generate a random matrix $A$ such that it is $NxN$
- Generate a random matrix $sol$ such that it is $Nx1$
- Multiply $A*sol$ to get $b$ such that it is $Nx1$
- Store $A$ to file and $sol$ to file
- Read files into new program and solve via Gaussian Elimination
- Compare results and display normalized error

It is my belief that $A$ = $A$ in $Ax=b$, and $sol$ = $x$ in $Ax=b$. The other student believes that $sol$ = $b$ in $Ax=b$ which to me makes no sense.

My position is that the instruction set has an error in the last 3 steps. If we store $A$ and $sol$ and use Gaussian Elimination, we cannot do that because we already have the $Ax$ piece of the system $Ax=b$. What we should also be storing is $b$, read in all the files, perform Gaussian Elimination on $A$ and $b$ to find a new $x$ and compare our $x$ to our original $sol$.

Looking for confirmation of my assumption or that I am clearly not grasping what I thought was a simple linear algebra problem...

Comment: Have you tried to see whether your friend's proposed rule works on some simple examples -- such as $A=({}^0_2\,{}^1_0)$ and $b=({}^1_0)$?

Comment: The student may have incorrectly remembered the formula that applies if $A$ is square and invertible: $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm not sure what you mean. The complexity of the matrices is not of concern. The concept (or flow) of the problem set is what is the issue. If $sol$ is in fact $b$ in the system $Ax=b$, then does multiplying $Ab = x$? I don't think that holds true.

Comment: I think @HenningMakholm is giving you a counterexample for the student's claim and asking you to verify it is actually a counterexample.

Comment: @user8734617 That's what I was thinking. Because if it turns out that $sol$ was the $b$, then simply multiplying $A*b$ to get $x$ would eliminate the need at all for Gaussian Elimination. The problem must be solved with Gaussian Elimination, not a matrix inverse and multiplication.

Comment: @user8734617 Yes I know that. Given the sequence of steps, if you were told to generate a random matrix $A$, and a random matrix $sol$, then multiply the two to get $b$, is it safe to presume that $A$ is $A$ and $sol$ is $x$ in the system $Ax=b$. This student seems to think that $sol$ is $b$, which would mean $Ab=x$ which is not right at all. I think the instructor simply messed up the assignment terms.

Comment: A reason you might use Gaussian elimination instead of multiplication by $A^{-1}$ is that finding $A^{-1}$ (given $A$) is at least as difficult as Gaussian elimination, so knowing that $x=A^{-1}b$ doesn't save you any work.

Comment: "What we should also be storing is b, read in all the files, perform Gaussian Elimination on A and b to find a new x and compare our x to our original sol." Yes, I think you are right. I would do it the way you said.

Comment: @pstatix I agree, reading through the steps - it does not make any sense. The third step from the bottom does look like it should say 'b' rather than 'sol'.